# Get timePicker value without showing timePicker dialog

Tags: android, button, layout, timepicker

How to get the selected time value without displaying `timePicker` dialog ?

Image below is my alarm design layout. When button clicked, I want it display the selected value **instead of pop up timePicker dialog.**

[image]

```
 alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

                // set time picker as current time
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                        false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hour   = hourOfDay;
            minute = minutes;
            updateTime(hour,minute);
        }
    };

    // Used to convert 24hr format to 12hr format with AM/PM values
    private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {

        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";


        String minutes = "";
        if (mins < 10)
            minutes = "0" + mins;
        else
            minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

        // Append in a StringBuilder
        String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),aTime,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Where should I change in the button click ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside button click, remove

`showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);` and replace with

```
int hour = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
int min = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
updateTime(hour,min);
```

The alarmTimePicker is follow the `timePicker` name where you use to initialize `timePicker`.

Eg:

```
TimePicker alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

Remove code below since dialog is not needed.

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

                // set time picker as current time
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                        false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hour   = hourOfDay;
            minute = minutes;
            updateTime(hour,minute);
        }
    };
```